# Compare two data tables from different input sources

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ado.net

We have two data tables in C# where one data table taking data from SQL database and second one taking data from  EXCEL sheet, when i am trying to compare that two data tables it is not working. Please check following scenario

1. comparison of two data tables where 1st taking data from SQL and 2nd from SQL - working fine.
2. comparison of two data tables where 1st taking data from EXCEL and 2nd from EXCEL -  working fine.
3. comparison of two data tables where 1st taking data from EXCEL and 2nd from SQL - NOT WORKING.

Can you please let us any problem with solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the data from both sources into an intermediate data format before you do the comparison. Otherwise format differences will show the columns as different even if the contents look the same to the eye.

Comment: Hi James... thanks for prompt response... can you please suggest any intermediate data format ... which will be best solution.

Comment: It depends on your data, you just need to make sure you are converting data from both sources to the same type before comparison, that's all that matters